# Does UPDATE INDEXES work for local indexes?

Tags: oracle, index, partitioning

I have two tables in Oracle 11.2. First is partitioned and has local index (non-prefixed):

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (col1 INT, col2 INT)
PARTITION BY LIST(col1)
(
    PARTITION p1 VALUES(1),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES(2)
);
CREATE INDEX table1_index on table1(col2) LOCAL;
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(2, 1);
```

Second table is similar but without partitions and index:

```
CREATE TABLE table2(col1 INT, col2 INT);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(1, 2);
```

When I exchange one of partition from `table1` with `table2` then index for this partition will be unusable. To avoid this I can use `UPDATE INDEXES`, so I do:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 EXCHANGE PARTITION p1
WITH TABLE table2 WITH VALIDATION UPDATE INDEXES;
```

But `UPDATE INDEXES` seem to doesn't work, because when I check status of index for this partition it's unusable.

```
SELECT partition_name, status FROM user_ind_partitions
WHERE index_name = 'TABLE1_INDEX';

PARTITION_NAME                 STATUS   
------------------------------ -------- 
P1                             UNUSABLE 
P2                             USABLE
```

For `GLOBAL` index it works as expected.

The question is: does `UPDATE INDEXES` work for `LOCAL` indexes when using `EXCHANGE PARTITION`?

Answer (score 5):

From the [Maintaining Partitions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16541/part_admin002.htm#i1107555) documentation:

> You can optionally specify if local indexes are also to be exchanged (INCLUDING INDEXES clause), and if rows are to be validated for proper mapping (WITH VALIDATION clause).
> [...]
>
> Unless you specify UPDATE INDEXES, the database marks UNUSABLE the global indexes or all global index partitions on the table whose partition is being exchanged. Global indexes or global index partitions on the table being exchanged remain invalidated.

I believe you'll need to create a matching index on `table2` and use both `INCLUDING INDEXES` and `UPDATE INDEXES` (but don't have a way of testing it right now).

Comment: Yes, it works, but I don't want to have an index on `table2`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't have a choice on that. Build the "local" index on `table2` once you've finished loading it, then exchange including it. The time that will take won't be different from the time it would take for Oracle to automatically rebuild the local indexes.

Comment: +1, it needs `INCLUDING INDEXES` only (for the local indexes).